# Unable to copy string a to string b, if I've already assigned a value to string b

Tags: c, pointers

When I uncomment line 13, the program reaches up to line 25 and then exits. What could possibly be the problem of me giving a value to name_1 before copying to it name_2's value? Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void strcpy(char* name_1, char* name_2);

int main()
{
    char *name_1, *name_2;
    name_1 = (char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    name_2 = (char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    printf("Insert name asap!: ");
    gets(name_2);
    //name_1 = "boufos";
    printf("The first name is: %s and the second: %s\n", name_1, name_2);
    strcpy(name_1, name_2);
    printf("The first name is: %s and the second: %s\n", name_1, name_2);
    return 0;
}

void strcpy(char* name_1, char* name_2)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (name_2[i] != '\0')
    {
        name_1[i] = name_2[i];
        i++;
    }
    name_1[str_length(name_2)] = '\0';

}

int str_length(char* name_2)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (name_2[i] != '\0')
    {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: name_2[i] != '\0'  is useless, null character is always false

Comment: also don't use `gets`

Comment: ... because `gets` is critically unsafe.  It has been not only deprecated, but *removed* from the latest version of the C standard.  Implementations provide it for compatibility with older code.

Comment: @JoeVanjik, `name_2[i] != '\0' ` is perfectly OK.

Comment: You can replace the horrible `name_1[str_length(name_2)] = '\0';` in your `strcpy` with just `name_1[i]= '\0';`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`name_1 = "boufos"` means that the variable `name_1` now points to the read-only memory that holds the constant string "boufos". Since this is a read-only memory, your `strcpy` call will fail at `name_1[i] = name_2[i];` (or `name_1[str_length(name_2)] = '\0'` if `name_2` is empty);.

Answer (score 5):

You're not giving `name_1` a value, at least not in the way you think.

When you do this:

```
name_1 = (char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
```

You make `name_1` point to a dynamically allocated area of memory.  But if you then do this:

```
name_1 = "boufos";
```

Now `name_1` points to the string constant `"boufos"`, overwriting the address of the malloc'ed memory and causing a memory leak.  String constants in C also typically reside in a read-only area of memory, so when you try to write to it, the program crashes.

You need to call `strcpy` (the real one, not your implementation) to copy strings.  This bring up another point: don't create functions with the same name as a system or library function.  Give it some other name like `my_strcpy`.